# how to avoid activity closing before the thread in fragment completed

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity, android-4.4-kitkat

Im having activity A.Inside that im having Fragment Fa.
  In Fa im having button Bu.
  When users clicks the Bu then it will start the thread.The status of progress of thread and after completing the result is shown in the activity via handler.
  But when user clicks the button the thread starts and b4 completion of thread when user clicks back button means then activity/fragment closed then handler become null.
  But thread runs and after completing throws null pointer for handler.

I need if user clicks back button means how to make fragment/activity will wait till thread need to complete?

The following are my configuration details
  Android minimum sdk version = 4.4

Comment: Why don't you use  progress dialog until thread finishes it's task ! With cancelable as false !?

Comment: Progress dialog is not needed.As per requirement. Any idea ?

Comment: If you want to restrict the fragment from sending message to the handler when it's no more visible,You can check isAdded() in your fragment to validate whether fragment is alive or not and send message to your activity !

Comment: Could you able to fix this issue ?